# I can't login to oracle system account

Tags: oracle, system

I recently installed oracle 12c and can't access the system local generated connection. (Ora-01017 error) eventhough I know for a fact its correct because I changed the password. Anyway, someone else on stackoverflow redirected me to this https://iwikte.wordpress.com/2008/11/28/unlock-oracle-system-account/, and I don't know how to set up these environment variables. I need help. If it makes any difference i'm using windows 10.
If these environment variables are not set automatically, do it manually
(export ORACLE_HOME=/opt/oracle/VIS/db/tech_st/10.2.0

export ORACLE_SID=VIS

export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin:$ORACLE_HOME/bin)

Answer (score 3):

Please first try without setting variables.

Please run SQLPlus as administrator and connect as sysdba without giving password. If your variables are set properly you can just type `sqlplus` in `cmd` if not please find `SqlPlus` in your programs. Then type:

```
conn / as sysdba
```

If that won't. Please go to your `ORACLE HOME` directory and edit `%ORACLE_HOME%\network\admin\sqlnet.ora` file and check if there is `SQLNET.AUTHENTICATION_SERVICES = (NTS)` if not `NTS` change to `NTS` and restart database. Then retry with `conn / as sysdba`

When connected you can just call:
`alter user sys identified by YOUR_NEW_PASS;` or for `SYSTEM` user `alter user SYSTEM identified by YOUR_NEW_PASS account unlock;` and login with new password.

By the way why do you need to log as `SYSTEM`? Not just `sys as sysdba`? Some [comparison](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/405/what-is-the-difference-between-sys-and-system-accounts-in-oracle-databases) about system accounts.

The instruction you got is for linux. In Windows one set environmental variables like shown [here](https://superuser.com/questions/949560/how-do-i-set-system-environment-variables-in-windows-10)

Answer (score 1):

from oracle version 12.2.x users cannot login using case insensitive passwords, even though SEC_CASE_SENSITIVE_LOGON = FALSE if PASSWORD_VERSIONS of user is not 10g.

following sql should show the PASSWORD_VERSIONS for a user.

```
select USERNAME,ACCOUNT_STATUS,PASSWORD_VERSIONS from dba_users;
USERNAME          ACCOUNT_STATUS    PASSWORD_VERSIONS 
---------------   --------------    -----------------
dummyuser         OPEN              11G 12C
```

to make PASSWORD_VERSIONS compatible with 10g

1. add/modify line in sqlnet.ora of database to have SQLNET.ALLOWED_LOGON_VERSION_SERVER=8
2. restart database
3. change/expire password for existing user
4. new users created will also have same settings

after above steps PASSWORD_VERSIONS should be something like this

```
select USERNAME,ACCOUNT_STATUS,PASSWORD_VERSIONS from dba_users;
USERNAME          ACCOUNT_STATUS    PASSWORD_VERSIONS 
---------------   --------------    -----------------
dummyuser         OPEN              10G 11G 12C
```

Comment: We are running Oracle 19c in a Multitenant Setup and required case insensitive passwords. It looks like the PASSWORD_VERSIONS are correctly set for the CDB but not for the PDB. Did I miss something? I would assume that the password for system should always be the same for all databases (CDB and PDB).