# Ora-01017 on oracle 12.2.0.1 - Not able to set case insensitive password

Tags: oracle, ora-01017

I need some help with setting login with case-insensitive password. I tried to set SEC_CASE_SENSITIVE_LOGON = FALSE but oracle client won't let me login with that case-insensitive password.

Getting error :  Ora-01017

Any leads on how I could achieve this for this oracle server version.

Answer (score 4):

from oracle version 12.2.x users cannot login using case insensitive passwords, even though SEC_CASE_SENSITIVE_LOGON = FALSE if PASSWORD_VERSIONS of user is not 10g.

following sql should show the PASSWORD_VERSIONS for a user.

```
select USERNAME,ACCOUNT_STATUS,PASSWORD_VERSIONS from dba_users;
USERNAME          ACCOUNT_STATUS    PASSWORD_VERSIONS 
---------------   --------------    -----------------
dummyuser         OPEN              11G 12C
```

to make PASSWORD_VERSIONS compatible with 10g

1. add/modify line in sqlnet.ora of database to have
   SQLNET.ALLOWED_LOGON_VERSION_SERVER=8
2. restart database
3. change/expire password for existing user

new users created will also have same settings
after above steps PASSWORD_VERSIONS should be something like this

```
select USERNAME,ACCOUNT_STATUS,PASSWORD_VERSIONS from dba_users;
USERNAME          ACCOUNT_STATUS    PASSWORD_VERSIONS 
---------------   --------------    -----------------
dummyuser         OPEN              10G 11G 12C
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/45341949/3134097

Comment: This worked for me,  thanks much ! Up-voting for that.  However, just wanted to check, if this tweak is not going to cause any other problems later on ?

Comment: I found that setting both SQLNET.ALLOWED_LOGON_VERSION_CLIENT and SQLNET.ALLOWED_LOGON_VERSION_SERVER to 11 works to have the password_version set to 10G, 11G, and 12C.